# Problemas para visualizar url de imagen en administrador de Django

Tags: django, django-admin, django-urls

Estoy creando un portafolio en Django y subí un proyecto al sitio, intento ver la imagen desde la URL del administrador y me muestra un error **404 NOT FOUND**. Cree el directorio:

> MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'

Y además agregué:

> MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

Aun así, me muestra error al querer abrir la imagen. Adjunto las siguientes imágenes esperando puedan ampliar el contexto sobre mi problema.
[image: AQUI EL ERROR]
[image: AQUI EL PANEL DE ADMIN DONDE TENGO LA URL DE LA IMG QUE QUIERO ABRIR EN EL NAV]
[image: AQUI AGREGUE MEDIA ROOT Y URL]

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que tener de esta forma tu archivo urls principal:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import include

# IMPORTA LAS VISTAS DE TU APP 
# IMPORTA LAS URLS SI ES QUE LAS TIENES EN UN ARCHIVO URLS DENTRO DE LA APP
from "Tu_App" import views
from "Tu_App" import urls

urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('', views.Tu_App, name='Tu_App'),
   path('Tu_App/', include('Tu_App.urls')),
       ]

# ESTA LINEA HACE QUE PUEDAS LEER LAS URL DE LAS IMAGENES
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Saludos!